# Access the type of a subclass from its superclass

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a superclass, `MySuperclass`, and a 2 subclasses of `MySuperclass`; `MySubclass1` and `MySubclass2`. I want to be able to call an instance method that relies on the type of the subclass.

For example, I want to be able to call `MySubclass.Serialize()` on any instance of a subclass of `MySuperclass` and have it call `Json.SerializeToBytes<T>(T toSerialize)` on that object, replacing `T` as appropriate.

```cs
public class MySuperclass 
{
    // of course, this does not work.
    public byte[] SerializeToBytes() 
        => Json.SerializeToBytes<typeof(this)>(this); 
}

public class MySubclass1 : MySuperclass
{
    ...
}

public class MySubclass2 : MySuperclass
{
    ...
}
```

Then I could do:

```cs
byte[] bytes; 
var mySubclass1Object = new MySubClass1();

bytes = mySubclass1Object.SerializeToBytes();

// the above is equivalent to (though the type parameter would normally be implied)
bytes = Json.SerializeToBytes<MySubclass1>(mySubclass1Object);
```

How can I achieve this?

---

As per a comment's request, the library I am using is the Utf8Json library. The `Json.SerializeToBytes<T>(T toSerialize)` is defined as: **

```cs
public static byte[] SerializeToBytes<T>(T obj)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>(obj);
}
```

### Footnotes

* I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102740/refer-to-current-class-instance-as-subclass-type-from-superclass). But it does not answer my question. In this case, they can refer to the subclass just using the type of the superclass, but here the serializer needs access to the subclass and all its extra methods and attributes to properly serialize it. They are also not passing the type as a type parameter to some method, which I need to do.

** I was hoping for this to be something that could be used in other situations too, where I can access the type of a subclass from a method defined in the superclass.

I don't want to use `override`, as it would require me to rewrite the `.Serialize()` method for each subclass

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Practical usage of virtual functions in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062102/practical-usage-of-virtual-functions-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Incidentally `Json.SerializeToBytes` uses reflection so it can see the actual object type that has been passed in

Comment: @Charlieface Would the solution in the question you have linked not require me to create a new method for each subclass, overriding the superclass's method? I'm doing this to save myself from writing a `.Serialize()` for like 20 classes.

Comment: Then the answer is my second comment. You can make one base function, without any override, and `Serialize` should work it out. **Which serializer/library are you using?**

Comment: @Charlieface Implementing something like `public byte[] SerializeToBytes() => Json.SerializeToBytes(this);` does not work successfully for any of the subclasses

Comment: @Charlieface I have added that information to the body of the post, however I was hoping for this to be something that could be used in other situations too, where I can access the type of a subclass from a method defined in the superclass

Comment: What is your question? Evething seems ok as it is. You dont need any override already.

Comment: You may find [this](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/02/curiouser-and-curiouser/) interesting. You want to genricize the base class as `MySuperclass<T> where T : MySuperclass` which looks crazy, but works. Then you can declare `string Serialize<T>` in the base class

Comment: You could also just pass `this.GetType()` and use the non-generic overload of `Serialize`. No need to use any recursive generics, particularly since you only want it for one purpose. In other words your SerializeToBytes method could be nongeneric as well. `JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, obj.GetType())`

Comment: Use the non generic version `public static byte[] SerializeToBytes(object obj)
{
    return JsonSerializer.NonGeneric.Serialize(obj);
}`

Comment: @JesúsLópez As I said in my post, this is not a question about serialization, but about OOP. I want to be able to use this more generally, and this was just an example. I have found a solution that works, it is below.

Comment: I would appreciate it if someone could let me know why they do not think this question is focused, and so much so, that it couldn't just have been tweaked a little?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Charlieface for the link to [the explanation of this](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/02/curiouser-and-curiouser/).

This implementation works, you need to cast to `T`.

```cs
public class MySuperclass<T> where T : MySuperclass<T>
{
    public byte[] SerializeToBytes() 
        => Json.SerializeToBytes((T)this); 
}

public class MySubclass1 : MySuperclass<MySubclass1>
{
    ...
}
```